# Use backref with manual citations

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

I'm using biblatex and biber and sometimes I create my own commands for special citations, like so:

```
\newcommand{\met}[3]{(\emph{Met.} #1\textsuperscript{#2}#3)\nocite{metaphysics}\mancite}
\met{987}{b}{5}
```

[image: \met{987}{b}{5}]

The thing is, I also use the backref option, so regular citations have back references in the bibliography, like "(See pp. 5-7)".

The same doesn't happen for my own custom citations, though, since `\nocite` adds the entry to the bibliography but doesn't care for where it was called from.

So is there a different way I can define my `\met` command and others of the sort to account for that and have back references pointing to them?

I'm actually trying to write my own biblatex style, so I'm thinking I could declare a cite command that doesn't print anything and use that… but it doesn't sound like a very elegant solution, so I'm hoping there's a better way to achieve what I want.

---

Edit: Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, backref]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\newcommand{\met}[3]{(\emph{Met.} #1\textsuperscript{#2}#3)\nocite{metaphysics}\mancite}

\begin{document}

    `Twas brillig, and the slithy toves did gyre and gimble in the wabe; all mimsy were the borogoves, and the mome raths outgrabe. \met{987}{b}{5} %\cite{metaphysics}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

`bib.bib` includes:

```
@incollection{metaphysics,
    Address = {New Jersey},
    Author = {Aristotle},
    Booktitle = {The Complete Works of {Aristotle}},
    Editor = {Jonathan Barnes},
    Publisher = {Princeton University Press},
    Title = {Metaphysics},
    Volume = {2},
    Year = {1995}}
```

Uncommenting `\cite{metaphysics}` adds "(cit. on p. 1)" to the references. I want that to happen with my `\met` command.

---

Edit 2:

I'm using `@incollection` because I was using bibtex with a crazy brazilian style file and that was my only option. Now I'm trying to move to biblatex little by little.

Anyway, using `shorttitle` seems great for this specific case, I didn't even know that existed. But I would have to declare a lot of new cite commands for many specific cases. And some of the citations might actually have nothing to do with the bibliography entry. For instance, to cite pre-socratic philosophers I'd use the Diels-Kranz numbering. So I could have one bibliography entry for Parmenides and another one for Heraclitus and they'd both be cited as something like "(28B1 DK)".

So I think it would be better to have something like `\nocite` except it would work with the back references, wouldn't it?

My first thought was to declare a cite command like `\hiddencite` and have it print nothing at all (or maybe just the `prenote` and `postnote`). I was just wondering if there wasn't a better option, since I just started using biblatex and I don't know much about it.

Comment: Best would be to define a custom cite command using Biblatex's facilities. But it would be much easier to help with a complete minimal example document we can work with.

Comment: I don't really follow. If the citation has nothing to do with the bibliography entry, why would you want a back reference claiming that the bibliography entry was cited by the citation?

Comment: Note that Biblatex supports customised pagination schemes which you can specify in `.bib` entries. I have some of these set up for various things. Some are quite specific e.g. `EHU`/`EPM`/`T` for Hume or `AK` for Kant (although I seem not to actually use the Kant one for some reason) and some are more general e.g. `bk\adddot`/`bks\adddot` etc.

Comment: Put this another way: originally you asked for a command inherently tied to a particular `.bib` entry. That's obviously only worth doing for something cited repeatedly and, even then, it might be best avoided. Now you're asking about using the same format for different entries without defining a different citation command for each entry. That's perfectly reasonable, so don't. Use entry-neutral commands for those cases, as you usually would. If I had to make a recommendation, I'd say avoid entry-specific commands. But for a book on Aristotle's *Metaphysics*, I can see the case for using one.

Comment: Do take a look at `biblatex-examples.bib`. It doesn't have any examples of custom pagination, but it does illustrate the use of `shorthand` (e.g. see `kant:ku`). These entries are annotated with comments concerning the use of various of Biblatex's features.

Comment: @cfr Ah, great, thank you. I'll look into the pagination schemes.

Comment: I mean the bibliography entry doesn't have anything to do with the citation because I never really look at the Diels-Kranz edition, for Parmenides there would be one edition in the bibliography and for Heraclitus another edition, but I'd use the DK numbering in the citations for my readers to follow in whatever edition they have. Then in the bibliography they'd see "Heraclitus. Edition whatever. Cited on pp. 2, 3, 4", and then they'd go to page 2, 3 and 4 and see the citation as "(28B1 DK)" even though the edition int he bibliography isn't the DK edition.

Comment: But I guess I'm just looking at it the wrong way. I get what you mean, you were a huge help, thanks. :)

Comment: Yes. I know. That's how I'd use the pagination schemes I mentioned. `AK`, for example, I use *just* as a pagination scheme. I've never even seen the AK edition itself, of course. Just like Bekker numbering and so on. So you treat it as a pagination scheme in Biblatex. You can use the same pagination scheme for multiple `.bib` entries or for one. Or you can include the pagination explicitly in the post note and Biblatex will omit the usual `p.` or whatever automatically. No need for a different cite command, though. I can't recall why I have the Hume ones - maybe those should be different..

Comment: I only had the time to really try the pagination scheme now and it works like a charm, thank you! And also I found out the `\citetitle` command is defined exactly like `\aristcite` in your answer, so I don't even have to define a new one, all I needed was the `shorttitle` field. :)

Comment: I defined `\aristcite` to use parentheses, but `\citetitle` is certainly similar. Glad the pagination schemes are useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the `.bib` entry is misclassified, in my opinion. Aristotle's *Metaphysics* is not a contribution to an edited anthology. It is, rather, a book in its own right. Here, it is simply included in a larger collection of his works. As such `@bookinbook` strikes me as a more appropriate classification than `@incollection`.

This changes the format of the bibliography entry, but that seems right: the title shouldn't be in quotation marks, but italics, as hinted at in your shorthand label, *Met.*

This means we can use something like the `shorttitle` field of the `.bib` entry for the shorthand. (Alternatively, you might look at the `shorthand` field.)

I would probably consider a different syntax for the custom citation command, but if you have stuff already using the syntax in the question, then that would be a pain to implement.

In that case, something like this might work:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@bookinbook{metaphysics,
    Address = {New Jersey},
    Author = {Aristotle},
    maintitle = {The Complete Works of {Aristotle}},
    Editor = {Jonathan Barnes},
    Publisher = {Princeton University Press},
    Title = {Metaphysics},
    Volume = {2},
    Year = {1995},
    shorttitle = {Met.}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, backref]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\aristcite}[\mkbibparens]{\usebibmacro{prenote}}{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}{\multicitedelim}{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\newcommand*\met[3]{\aristcite[][#1\textsuperscript{#2}#3]{metaphysics}}

\begin{document}

  `Twas brillig, and the slithy toves did gyre and gimble in the wabe; all mimsy were the borogoves, and the mome raths outgrabe. \met{987}{b}{5}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: back reference to custom citation]

By the way, do you have the original Greek for this quotation, by any chance? ;)

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful and I'll use it for authors that I cite often… but there's still an issue I described in another edit. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Are you meaning that Jabberwocky isn't by Aristotle? `;-)`

Comment: Here's a Greek version: http://www76.pair.com/keithlim/jabberwocky/translations/greek1.html

Comment: @egreg But is it the *original*? It says it is a translation into New Testament Greek ;).

Comment: @cfr I'm taking another look at this and you got me curious: "I would probably consider a different syntax"… What would you do differently?

Comment: @danielbmarques I don't recall exactly but I would try to keep the syntax as like the default citation commands as possible, making it easy to create a multicite command, for example, and to cite multiple pages/sections. The 3 arguments to `\met` are not very flexible. On the other hand, if you're certain you'll never need the flexibility, you might not think there is any reason to introduce the additional complexity.

Comment: I see. The three arguments are bugging me a little too, but I want the superscript and it seems like the easiest way. Anyway, thanks!